# Firebase dynamic links shows unverified in playstore console

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, google-play-console, firebase-dynamic-links

Recently, I received a warning from the Google Play Store about Firebase Dynamic Links.

[image]

[image]

I'm concerned about how to add a digital asset link to a Firebase Dynamic Link domain.